# Pass parent task arguments to all celery subtasks

Tags: python, celery

Given the following tasks:

```
@app.task
def task1(v1, v2):
    return "val3"

@app.task
def task2(v1, v2, v3):
    return "val4"

@app.task
def task3(v1, v2, v3):
    return "val4"
```

Given the following workflow:

```
workflow = chain(
    task1.s(),
    group(
        task2.s(),
        task3.s()
    )
)

result = workflow.delay("val1", "val2")
```

How can I get celery to pass the original arguments `val1` and `val2` to `task2` and `task3` inside the group. The result of `task1` is the only value passed on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`task.s()` is just a signature (a partial function). You can pass some arguments to it at any time if you want.

So you can use this workflow.

```
x = 'my first arg'
y = 'my second arg'

workflow = chain(task1.s(x, y), group(task2.s(x, y), task3.s(x, y)))
result = workflow.delay()
```

Also note that the result of first task is passed as first argument to next task.